# highcharts zoomable 6 month line graph

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts

I want a 6 month graph that shows the monthly view by default but is zoom-able down to the day.

Today our 6 month graph we have:

```
xAxis: {
title: {
text: 'Temperature'
},
categories: ['Oct','Nov','Dec','Jan','Feb','Mar',]
series: [
{ name: 'my series',
visible: true,
data: [5,10,15,5,7,8,]},
{ name: 'another series',
visible: true,
data: [0,0,0,146,80,0,]},
```

This works great for monthly.

To get the daily data I can push in the roughly 30*6 elements into the data. Also I tried using:

```
pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 11, 1),
pointInterval: 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000 // one day
```

like this example: http://jsfiddle.net/7Mmee/9/

but the problem is not every month has 30 days, also the bottom of the chart doesn't show the categories.

Im sure there is a simple way to do this that I am missing.

thanks
Joel

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks as though you're trying to show one data point per month. If this is the case, I would recommend assigning each data point a time and changing the date formatter.

```
//Example 1: Each data point has a time, with a date formatter:
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: { //custom date formats for different scales
            second: '%H:%M:%S',
            minute: '%H:%M',
            hour: '%H:%M',
            day: '%e. %b',
            week: '%e. %b',
            month: '%b', //month formatted as month only
            year: '%Y'
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [
            {x: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1), y: 1}, //one data point for each month
            {x: Date.UTC(2010, 1, 1), y: 4},
            {x: Date.UTC(2010, 2, 1), y: 9},
            {x: Date.UTC(2010, 3, 1), y: 16},
            {x: Date.UTC(2010, 4, 1), y: 25},
            {x: Date.UTC(2010, 5, 1), y: 36}
        ]
    }]
});
```

However, it also seems you want to zoom down to the 'day' level. If this is the case, it makes sense to add all your data points to the series, and use highcharts' `zoomType` property, perhaps in combination with the date formatter.

```
//Example 2: Each data point represents a day, and we use the 'zoomType' feature:
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        zoomType: 'x'
    },

    series: [{
        data: [
            {x: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1), y: 1}, //one data point for each day
            {x: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 2), y: 1.1},
            {x: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 3), y: 1.4},
            {x: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 4), y: 1.8},
            {x: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 5), y: 2.5},
            {x: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 6), y: 3.8}
        ]
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work:

You can pass your data as a pair of timestamp and value, check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/CAKQH/310/